# Use application.pathseparator for files that are in different folders

Tags: excel, vba

I'm copying data from `secondfile.xlsm` into a file named `firstfile.xlsm`. This code works if they are in the same folder. I need the two files in separate folders however, and once I separate them, the `secondfile.xlsm` can no longer be found.

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim filename As String
    filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "secondfile.xlsm"

    Dim wk As Workbook
    Set wk = Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)

    Dim rgSource As Range, rgDestination As Range

    ' set rgsource = [workbook].[worksheet].[range]
    Set rgSource = wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B7") 'Sheet1 from "secondfile.xlsm"
    Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1") 'Destination from firstfile.xlsm

    rgSource.Copy
    rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    wk.Close saveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: After copying the file, you need to also update the path to the 2nd file. Currently it is still looking for the 2nd file in the same palce as where the 1st file is. You need something like `ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "MYFOLDER\secondfile.xlsm"` or then something like `"C:\MYFOLDER\secondfile.xlsm"`. Specify the path accordingly.

Comment: BTW you do not need `Application.PathSeparator`. You can also write `ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "MYFOLDER\secondfile.xlsm"` as `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MYFOLDER\secondfile.xlsm"` if you are working on a Win PC.

Comment: I should've specified that I need the code to run both in mac and windows as others will be using what I'm going to build

Comment: In that case yes do use `Application.PathSeparator` but the main point still remains the same. You will have to specify the complete path.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't the paths for mac and windows be formatted differently? So I would need to specify two different complete paths with some kind of conditional statement to use either the mac path or windows path?

Comment: Yes whatever the path is you will have to specify that accordingly. There are lot of codes online which shows how to write separate code using #IF-#ENDIF for win and mac. Once you identify the path for mac for ex: `"MacBook:Users:Documents:secondfile.xlsm"` then simply use that